# Is it possible to perform projection operators on a recursive MongoDB structure?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a `comments` collection, whose schema looks like this:

```
{
    id: string,
    username: string,
    upvotes: number,
    downvotes: number,
    text: string,
    date: Date,
    replies: [{
        // Same structure, nested.
    }]
}
```

Suppose I call `find` (from the Node.js driver) like so:

```
// Assume an `id` variable exists, corresponding to the id of a top-level comment.
const commCollection = db.collection('comments');
const comments = await commCollection.find({ id }, { 
    projection: {
        _id: 0,
        id: 0
    }
});
```

My understanding is that this would return all comments with a specific `id`, but not return the `id` (or the `_id`) values themselves. However, it does nothing to remove the `id` attribute in the replies (or in their replies, and so on). My question, then, is whether this is possible in MongoDB. That is, an effect similar to the `$[]` operator with `$push` and `$set`.

Comment: Hi, What is the maximum level of nesting?

Comment: @HanielBaez Theoretically, none.

Comment: You should not let a document grow without boundaries because: The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes and MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents. Also consider if you really need to consume all comments at once.

Comment: I see what you mean. For my specific use case, I don't anticipate anywhere near that, but I can understand why it might still be a bad idea. The last point you bring you seems like something I could exploit. How do you suggest I refactor accordingly? I could, e.g., create a new object when the depth = 5 or so, for instance.

Comment: I don't think this can be done.

Comment: If you are asking whether you should do this in the first place, my suggestion is this is a premature optimization.

Comment: @D.SM Do you mean my depth idea (if so, I understand). I suppose I could just use a loop and do it. Strange that they haven't done this.

Comment: The idea to exclude id fields. You will save maybe 10% of data transfer, less if there is any text at all.

Comment: @Rahul take a look at [The Subset Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern), it fit your use case.